# Read txt file using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, readfile

I need to read a file from the browser and I CANNOT use ajax.. it is necessary to be read locally..

this is not a duplicate from [Reading a file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404991/reading-a-file-using-javascript)

how can I do that?

ps: I also CANNOT use an engine like V8 http://code.google.com/p/v8/ I need to read it with the current native API from javascript!.. is there any way to do that?

ps2: it must run only with chrome, or firefox! IE and others doesnt matter

Comment: Make use of iframe in HTML5

Comment: Maybe an explanation of your limitations would help us suggest solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dQxj9/)**

```
 function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files;

    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function (f) {
                return function (e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    alert(contents);
                };
            })(f);
            r.readAsText(f);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Failed to load files");
    }
}
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
```